# Weird lines when using tfidvectoriser, may be caused by replacing with ' '?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science

i posted on here yesterday about making a text linear regression model for predicting sentiment, what i'm wondering is after lowercasing the text, removing any stopword/punctuation and numbers, i'm left with weird lines on some of my text features.

```
     ['_______',


'__________',
 '__________ pros',
 '____________',
 '____________ pros',
 '_____________',
 '_____________ pros',
 'aa',
 'aa waist',
 'ab',
 'abdomen',
 'ability',
 'able',
 'able button',
 'able buy',
```

i'm thinking prehaps its because for punctuations and numbers, i replaced them with a space? i'm still not absolutely sure.

Another question is how do i structure this properly for linear regression? should i represent each sentence by a column of their features and feed it into the network? but how would i handle if the matrix is sparse?

Sorry just learning more about text preprocessing

here are my cleaning steps: lets assume a sentence is like this 'this dress in a lovely platinum is feminine and fits perfectly, easy to wear and comfy, too! highly recommend!'

1. lowercase

   AllSentences['Sentence'] = AllSentences['Sentence'].map(lambda x: x.lower())

2.remove stop words

```
  stop = stopwords.words('english')
    AllSentences['Sentences_without_stopwords'] = AllSentences['Sentence'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
```

3.remove numbers

```
AllSentences['Sentences_without_stopwords_punc'] = AllSentences['Sentences_without_stopwords'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',x))
AllSentences['Sentences_without_stopwords_punc'] = AllSentences['Sentences_without_stopwords_punc'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\d+', '',x))
```

4. test/train split, tfidvectorise

   ```
   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
    test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

      vect_word = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=20000, lowercase=True, 
      analyzer='word',stop_words= 'english',ngram_range=(1,3),dtype=np.float32)

   tr_vect = vect_word.fit_transform(X_train)
   ts_vect = vect_word.transform(X_test)
   ```

which gave me the above output for feature names?

Comment: Can you share how you're cleaning up the string? Also, what features are you extracting?

Comment: @JamesMchugh i've added the above steps to the text, i'm trying to extract features which may represent good or bad sentiment

Comment: Are you using linear regression or logistic regression? For sentiment analysis, a classifier should suffice. I may be incorrect, but I do not see the application for a linear regression model here.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `TfidfVectorizer` is a great place to start for an initial attempt at sentiment analysis. To avoid sparsity in your feature vectors, you may want to start with less features and work your way up depending on how your models perform. You could possibly make it a hyperparameter while training and use `GridSearch` and a `Pipeline` to find the best value for it. See an example of that [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html). Depending on how this goes, a more robust implementation might use [word embeddings](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-word-embedding-and-word2vec-652d0c2060fa). However, this would most likely introduce more complexity to your model.

The weird lines in the string are underscore characters that must have been in the source text. They were not cleaned up in your cleanup process because you used the `re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',x)` to remove non-word characters and non-whitespace from your string. Underscores are part of the word character set (`'\w'`), so they were not cleaned up.

I should also point out that most of your custom cleaning should not be necessary, as the `TfidfVectorizer` should be able to handle this for you. For example, you remove stop words, and then `TfidfVectorizer` tries to remove them as well. This is also the case with removing punctuation and numbers from the string. `TfidfVectorizer` takes a `token` parameter, and you can pass a regular expression to it to pick what characters you want to keep in a token. If you only want alpha characters in your string, this regex for the token argument should suffice to handle the cleaning for you: `'[a-zA-Z]'`. Again, I do not use the `'\w'` character set here since it includes underscores (and numbers).

As you have already ran the `fit_transform` method of `TfidfVectorizer` on your train set and the `transform` method on your test set, the samples in those sets should be ready for training/testing. They need not be further processed.